# In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, arguments, evaluation

The issue: Function not able to evaluate arguments properly.
The symptom: When attempting to evaluate the `x` and `y` arguments in a ggplot `aes()` statement, the function returns an error, saying not able to find the object being passed in the argument, and then giving the error:

```
In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

Here is the code:

```
plot_vote_by_state <-
  function(dsrce,
       x_axis_srce,
       y_axis_srce,
       point_labels = NULL,
       point_color_key = NULL,
       data_fit_srce = NULL,
       title_txt = NULL,
       sub_title_txt = NULL,
       x_lbl_txt = NULL,
       y_lbl_txt = NULL,
       caption_txt = NULL) {
basic_plot <- ggplot(
  dsrce,
  aes(
    x_axis_srce,
    y_axis_srce
  )
) + geom_point()
print(basic_plot)
  }
```

Here is a link to the data: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AolqFDwBowVjlMBVELC8qhwXkt8jPQ?e=m63GYO

Here is the command line that I'm using to invoke the function:

```
plot_vote_by_state(dsrce = GDP_vs_pcnt_Biden_Vote, x_axis_srce = GDP_per_Capita, y_axis_srce = Vote_share_pcnt)
```

Heres a look at the first row of the dsrce argument from within the debug environment; this shows the column names:

```
Browse[2]> dsrce
  State Vote_share_pcnt    GDP   fit Population GDP_per_Capita per_capita_fit EC    Ten_yr_avg_unemp Unemp_fit


1 AL              0.366   908. 0.475    5024279           181.          0.430 TRUMP             7.33     0.513
```

However, when I try to look at one of the `aes()` arguments while in debug, I get this:

```
Browse[2]> x_axis_srce
Error: object 'GDP_per_Capita' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

When the `GDP_per_Capita` column is clearly there in the `dsrce`.

If I manually run ggplot while in the debug environment by typing the actual argument names into the `aes()` argument (ie: not using the `x_axis_srce` and `y_axis_srce` assigned variables) the plot function works as it should.

But it will not work if I try to use the assigned `x_axis_srce` and `y_axis_srce` variables that are passed through to the funtion.

It also blows up if I do a `colnames(dsrce)` command while in the debug environment:

```
Browse[2]> colnames(dsrce)


[1] "State"            "Vote_share_pcnt"  "GDP"              "fit"              "Population"       "GDP_per_Capita"   "per_capita_fit"   "EC"              
 [9] "Ten_yr_avg_unemp" "Unemp_fit"       
Warning messages:
1: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
4: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
5: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
6: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
7: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
8: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
9: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
10: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

Help!  What's going on here?

Comment: Your current use of the function is using "standard evaluation", so `aes(x_axis_srce, y_axis_srce)` is wrong: `ggplot2` is using non-standard evaluation (NSE), so will look for a column labeled literally `"x_axis_srce"` in the data, which it won't find. See **Programming with ggplot2**, specifically the [*Indirectly referring to variables*](https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html#indirectly-referring-to-variables) section.

Answer (score 2):

Your current use of the function is using "standard evaluation", so `aes(x_axis_srce, y_axis_srce)` is wrong: `ggplot2` is using non-standard evaluation (NSE), so will look for a column labeled literally `"x_axis_srce"` in the data, which it won't find. See **Programming with ggplot2**, specifically the [*Indirectly referring to variables*](https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html#indirectly-referring-to-variables) section.

However, even that reference is a little outdated, as `aes_` and `aes_string` are both soft-deprecated, both deferring to a new strategy: `.data$` or `{{.}}`. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function-1.

Try this instead:

```r
plot_vote_by_state <-
  function(dsrce,
           x_axis_srce,
           y_axis_srce,
           point_labels = NULL,
           point_color_key = NULL,
           data_fit_srce = NULL,
           title_txt = NULL,
           sub_title_txt = NULL,
           x_lbl_txt = NULL,
           y_lbl_txt = NULL,
           caption_txt = NULL) {
    basic_plot <- ggplot(
      dsrce,
      aes(
        {{ x_axis_srce }},
        {{ y_axis_srce }}
      )
    ) + geom_point()
    print(basic_plot)
  }
```